# ERROR! Unexpected end of file in JSON when try to create Vite(react) project

Tags: reactjs, vite

this error always show when i try to start server react-vitejs project

current use node v18.16.0 how to solve this problem help me pls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYPDz.png)

i'm try to update node version and create with pnpm but it still not work again

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.